# Airflow upstream task in "none status" status, but downstream tasks executed

Tags: airflow

As screenshot:

[image]

Any idea why this would occur, and how would I go about troubleshooting it?

--

Update:

It's "none status" not "queued" as I originally interpreted

The DAG run occurred on 3/8 and last relevant commit was on 3/1. But I'm having trouble finding the same DAG run....will keep investigating

Comment: does it really "queued"?  It looks like No status to me.  If you are using default UI, "queued" should have gray border color.  To me, this DAG coloring happens if I add the `drop_staging_table_if_exists` task after it ran or I modified the name  of the task. Does that apply to you?

Comment: @Emma Ur right it's actually "none status". It's an old DAG though, it's not been modified for a long time, and has run hundreds of times since last edit

Comment: @Emma Ok figured out, while DAG runs (along with almost everything else) are listed in order of most recent first, "recent tasks" are listed with least recent first, so the UI took me to an old DAG run instead of the most recent one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Queued status. It's None status.

This can happen in one of the following cases:

1. The task `drop_staging_table_if_exists` was added after `create_staging_table` started to run.
2. The task `drop_staging_table_if_exists` used to have a different `task_id` in the past.
3. The task `drop_staging_table_if_exists` was somewhere else in the workflow and you changed the dependencies after the DAG run started.

Note Airflow currently doesn't support DAG versioning (It will be supported in future versions when [AIP-36 DAG Versioning](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-36+DAG+Versioning) is completed) This means that Airflow constantly reload the DAG structure, so changes that you make will also be reflected on past runs - This is by design! and it's very useful for cases where you want to backfill past runs.

Either way, if you will start a new run or clear this specific run the issue you are facing will be resolved.

Comment: Looks like it is indeed "none status", but it is an old DAG that has not been modified, but has been running hourly + via API for quite a while. (DAG parallism set to 1). Updating question

Comment: Ok figured out, while DAG runs (along with almost everything else) are listed in order of most recent first, "recent tasks" are listed with least recent first, so the UI took me to an old DAG run instead of the most recent one...

Comment: Given it's an old DAG run, one of the three may very well have happened